# Multi schema XSDs node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

This may be on the same lines as this:
[node-soap multiple import schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792452/node-soap-multiple-import-schemas)
But I coudnt find the fix.

I have a WSDL which refers to one XSD and this XSD refers another one.

Parent.wsdl --> a.xsd -->b.xsd

node-soap is not able to create namespace for b.xsd due to which the soap request packet does not have entry for b.xsd types.

Please let me know how can I address this.

I have tried node-soap for 1 xsd scenario and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I know lots of time has gone but was you able to resolve this issue?